Astra_Camera: Wait for device to connected
I setup the Astra Camera using this link. It give the message after launching the command roslaunch astra_camera astra.launch.
roslaunch astra_camera astra.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/cbdb0e32-3e25-11ef-a4dd-ec0ec46b47b9/roslaunch-turtlebot-Aspire-E3-111-4765.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://169.226.47.102:35829/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot2/camera/camera/camera_name: camera
 * /robot2/camera/camera/color_depth_synchronization: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/color_format: RGB
 * /robot2/camera/camera/color_fps: 30
 * /robot2/camera/camera/color_height: 480
 * /robot2/camera/camera/color_info_uri: 
 * /robot2/camera/camera/color_width: 640
 * /robot2/camera/camera/connection_delay: 100
 * /robot2/camera/camera/depth_align: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/depth_format: Y11
 * /robot2/camera/camera/depth_fps: 30
 * /robot2/camera/camera/depth_height: 480
 * /robot2/camera/camera/depth_scale: 1
 * /robot2/camera/camera/depth_width: 640
 * /robot2/camera/camera/device_num: 1
 * /robot2/camera/camera/enable_color: True
 * /robot2/camera/camera/enable_d2c_viewer: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/enable_depth: True
 * /robot2/camera/camera/enable_ir: True
 * /robot2/camera/camera/enable_point_cloud: True
 * /robot2/camera/camera/enable_point_cloud_xyzrgb: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/enable_publish_extrinsic: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/flip_color: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/flip_depth: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/flip_ir: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/ir_format: Y10
 * /robot2/camera/camera/ir_fps: 30
 * /robot2/camera/camera/ir_height: 480
 * /robot2/camera/camera/ir_info_uri: 
 * /robot2/camera/camera/ir_width: 640
 * /robot2/camera/camera/oni_log_level: verbose
 * /robot2/camera/camera/oni_log_to_console: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/oni_log_to_file: False
 * /robot2/camera/camera/product_id: 
 * /robot2/camera/camera/publish_tf: True
 * /robot2/camera/camera/serial_number: 
 * /robot2/camera/camera/soft_filter: 2
 * /robot2/camera/camera/soft_filter_max_diff: 16
 * /robot2/camera/camera/soft_filter_max_speckle_size: 480
 * /robot2/camera/camera/tf_publish_rate: 10.0
 * /robot2/camera/camera/vendor_id: 0x2bc5
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.17

NODES
  /robot2/camera/
    camera (astra_camera/astra_camera_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.226.47.102:11311

process[robot2/camera/camera-1]: started with pid [4782]
[ INFO] [1720555121.468262625]: Starting camera node...
[ INFO] [1720555121.495446753]: Creating camera node...
[ INFO] [1720555121.495746386]: OBCameraNodeFactory::OBCameraNodeFactory
[ INFO] [1720555121.495978265]: Initializing OBCameraNodeFactory...
[ INFO] [1720555121.561233415]: init Done
[ INFO] [1720555121.561495175]: Creating camera node done...
[ INFO] [1720555121.561697318]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555121.561797892]: Found 0 devices
[ INFO] [1720555122.562144784]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555122.564463818]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555123.561558626]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555123.567952440]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555124.561460084]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555124.571698225]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555125.561365970]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555125.574903727]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555126.561405502]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555126.577093138]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555127.561386689]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555127.580382101]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555128.561641444]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555128.584718140]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555129.561425540]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555129.588841211]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555130.561970603]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555130.595418258]: Query device
[ INFO] [1720555131.561523275]: wait for device  to be connected
[ INFO] [1720555131.599169408]: Query device
^C[robot2/camera/camera-1] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done



I received these messages iteratively with different number.
The output of lsusb is
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b47f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
    Bus 001 Device 012: ID 2bc5:0401
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

The output of lsusb -v for ID 2bc5:0401 is
    Bus 001 Device 012: ID 2bc5:0401
    Device Descriptor:
    bLength 18
    bDescriptorType 1
    bcdUSB 2.00
    bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
    bDeviceSubClass 0
    bDeviceProtocol 0
    bMaxPacketSize0 64
    idVendor 0x2bc5
    idProduct 0x0401
    bcdDevice 0.01
    iManufacturer 1 ORBBEC
    iProduct 2 ASTRA
    iSerial 0
    bNumConfigurations 1
    Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 2
    wTotalLength 145
    bNumInterfaces 3
    bConfigurationValue 1
    iConfiguration 0
    bmAttributes 0x80
    (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower 500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 4
    bInterfaceNumber 0
    bAlternateSetting 0
    bNumEndpoints 2
    bInterfaceClass 255 Vendor Specific Class
    bInterfaceSubClass 0
    bInterfaceProtocol 0
    iInterface 3 ORBBEC Depth Sensor
    Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength 7
    bDescriptorType 5
    bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes 2
    Transfer Type Bulk
    Synch Type None
    Usage Type Data
    wMaxPacketSize 0x0200 1x 512 bytes
    bInterval 1
    Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength 7
    bDescriptorType 5
    bEndpointAddress 0x82 EP 2 IN
    bmAttributes 2
    Transfer Type Bulk
    Synch Type None
    Usage Type Data
    wMaxPacketSize 0x0200 1x 512 bytes
    bInterval 1
    Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 4
    bInterfaceNumber 1
    bAlternateSetting 0
    bNumEndpoints 0
    bInterfaceClass 1 Audio
    bInterfaceSubClass 1 Control Device
    bInterfaceProtocol 0
    iInterface 4 ORBBEC Audio Device
    AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 36
    bDescriptorSubtype 1 (HEADER)
    bcdADC 1.00
    wTotalLength 43
    bInCollection 1
    baInterfaceNr( 0) 2
    AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 12
    bDescriptorType 36
    bDescriptorSubtype 2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
    bTerminalID 1
    wTerminalType 0x0201 Microphone
    bAssocTerminal 0
    bNrChannels 2
    wChannelConfig 0x0003
    Left Front (L)
    Right Front (R)
    iChannelNames 0
    iTerminal 0
    AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 36
    bDescriptorSubtype 3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
    bTerminalID 2
    wTerminalType 0x0101 USB Streaming
    bAssocTerminal 0
    bSourceID 3
    iTerminal 0
    AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 13
    bDescriptorType 36
    bDescriptorSubtype 6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
    bUnitID 3
    bSourceID 1
    bControlSize 2
    bmaControls( 0) 0x03
    bmaControls( 0) 0x00
    Mute Control
    Volume Control
    bmaControls( 1) 0x03
    bmaControls( 1) 0x00
    Mute Control
    Volume Control
    bmaControls( 2) 0x03
    bmaControls( 2) 0x00
    Mute Control
    Volume Control
    iFeature 0
    Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 4
    bInterfaceNumber 2
    bAlternateSetting 0
    bNumEndpoints 0
    bInterfaceClass 1 Audio
    bInterfaceSubClass 2 Streaming
    bInterfaceProtocol 0
    iInterface 0
    Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 4
    bInterfaceNumber 2
    bAlternateSetting 1
    bNumEndpoints 1
    bInterfaceClass 1 Audio
    bInterfaceSubClass 2 Streaming
    bInterfaceProtocol 0
    iInterface 0
    AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 7
    bDescriptorType 36
    bDescriptorSubtype 1 (AS_GENERAL)
    bTerminalLink 2
    bDelay 1 frames
    wFormatTag 1 PCM
    AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength 20
    bDescriptorType 36
    bDescriptorSubtype 2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
    bFormatType 1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
    bNrChannels 2
    bSubframeSize 2
    bBitResolution 16
    bSamFreqType 4 Discrete
    tSamFreq[ 0] 8000
    tSamFreq[ 1] 16000
    tSamFreq[ 2] 32000
    tSamFreq[ 3] 48000
    Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 5
    bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN
    bmAttributes 13
    Transfer Type Isochronous
    Synch Type Synchronous
    Usage Type Data
    wMaxPacketSize 0x00c0 1x 192 bytes
    bInterval 4
    bRefresh 0
    bSynchAddress 0
    AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength 7
    bDescriptorType 37
    bDescriptorSubtype 1 (EP_GENERAL)
    bmAttributes 0x01
    Sampling Frequency
    bLockDelayUnits 0 Undefined
    wLockDelay 0 Undefined
    Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
    bLength 10
    bDescriptorType 6
    bcdUSB 2.00
    bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
    bDeviceSubClass 0
    bDeviceProtocol 0
    bMaxPacketSize0 64
    bNumConfigurations 0
    Device Status: 0x0000
    (Bus Powered)

How can I figure out the problem?
